# How to retrieve an xml document and group nodes based on attribute value using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

So lets assume that my transaction body is completely empty when I start the transformation.

I have an xml file with some data like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<codes>
    <code sourceCode="10" targetCode="06" area="MAIL"/>
    <code sourceCode="11" targetCode="1" area="PROFESSION"/>
    <code sourceCode="11" targetCode="11" area="HOME"/>
    <code sourceCode="12" targetCode="13" area="HOME"/>
    <code sourceCode="12" targetCode="3" area="HOME"/>
    <code sourceCode="13" targetCode="10" area="PROFESSION"/>
    <code sourceCode="14" targetCode="01" area="WORK"/>
    <code sourceCode="14" targetCode="05" area="MAIL"/>
</codes>
```

I need the result to be something like this:

```
<codes>
    <code>
        <sourceCode>10</sourceCode>
        <areas>
            <area>MAIL</area>
        </areas>
    </code>
    <code>
        <sourceCode>11</sourceCode>
        <areas>
            <area>PROFESSION</area>
            <area>HOME</area>
        </areas>
    </code>
    <!-- This code has two different targetCodes with the same area 
        but in the result it should not have the same area twice in the areas list -->
    <code>
        <sourceCode>12</sourceCode>
        <areas>
            <area>HOME</area>
        </areas>
    </code>
    <code>
        <sourceCode>13</sourceCode>
        <areas>
            <area>PROFESSION</area>
        </areas>
    </code>
    <code>
        <sourceCode>14</sourceCode>
        <areas>
            <area>WORK</area>
            <area>MAIL</area>
        </areas>
    </code>
</codes>
```

There are two challenges here.
First one is that the original document is not the body of the transaction but you have to retrieve it inside the xsl.
Second one is the actual transformation and how to achieve this grouping by sourceCode attribute while eliminating the targetCode attribute entirely and not having duplicate areas.

At the start of the XSL file this is how I retrieve the XML document:

```
<xsl:variable name="lookupDoc" select="document('../common/lookup/mapping.xml')"/>
```

EDIT:
Finally I would also like to filter out area "MAIL" completely. So in the final xml the first code element would be eliminated while the last one would just have one area ("WORK").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a template like

```
  <xsl:template match="codes">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="code" group-by="@sourceCode">
        <xsl:copy>
          <sourceCode>
            <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
          </sourceCode>
          <areas>
            <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(current-group()/@area)">
              <area>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              </area>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </areas>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

and then push `<xsl:apply-templates select="$lookupDoc/node()"/>` through that template.

Comment: Thank you Martin!
And if I wanted to also filter out completely the <code> elements with @area = "MAIL" how would I achieve that? Sorry for the bonus question. :-)

In the final xml i would expect the first code element (sourceCode 10) to be eliminated entirely while the last one (sourceCode 14) to just have 1 area (WORK).

I am editing my question accordingly so you can also add this to your answer.

Comment: @xray1986, does `<xsl:for-each-group select="code[not(@area = 'MAIL')]" group-by="@sourceCode">` instead of `<xsl:for-each-group select="code" group-by="@sourceCode">` solve that? Otherwise ask a new question with the details

Comment: Yes it does! Thanks again for helping out!